Why is "can"/"kann" often not used in German where it would be in English?
In English it is common to use the word "can" where I do not see it in corresponding phrases in German, for example:

I can make out the mountains in the distance.


Ich erkenne die Berge in der Ferne.

I also see numerous expressions in the dictionary which use "can" in English but not "kann" in the German translation, for example:

as far as I can see


soweit ich sehe


I'll see what can be done.


Ich will sehen, was sich tun lässt.

Why is this? Is it considered bad style to use "kann" very often, or is it just a matter of particular expressions which do not use it?

It's different languages. I don't concur with your first example. My natural way to formulate would be "Ich kann die Berge in der Ferne sehen". Your quoted version is a slightly higher register.

All those examples have clear German equivalents using 'können', and in fact I'd probably use them instead of the translations you give.

Another example, which might help highlight the idiomatic differences is I can see how (you would think so).

The question is not quite clear. The title has a why? question, but the body  states a different question. Please clarify what exactly you want to know.

It might be fruitful to change perspective and consider the difference between English and German as a peculiarity of the English language. Being a native German speaker, I might be biased here, and of course, from a mere logical point of view, the difference between two things can never be understood as an attribute of only one of the things but is a feature of the relation between the two things.
But it might be helpful to start wondering why English has those instances of can in the first place. I tried to do that. Although I am not super confident in some cases, I hope it helps shed some light on your question:
Redundancy
Notice that the can is redundant in some cases. In the examples

As far as I can see [there is no problem with the new approach].


I can make out the mountains in the distance.

The can has no logical value. Yes, it does refer to an ability of the subject, but that would be implied already if the can was omitted. (It is hard for me to describe, why it is there in the first place. Maybe it makes sense to ask about this in an English forum.)
This redundancy is avoided in German. So, whenever the can is redundant, you will likely not use a form of können in German.
Non-Redundant use of can
In the example

I can see how [you dislike him]

can has an actual function. It characterizes the relation between the speaker "I" and the addressee "you". I am not 100 % sure how to describe this relation. I would say that by using a modal verb referring to some subjective capability, the proposition gets more subjectivized. Similar things exist in German. Consider the translations

Ich verstehe[, warum du ihn nicht leiden kannst]
Ich kann verstehen[, warum du ihn nicht leiden kannst]

I would say, the latter vibrates more empathy by stressing the subjective side of the problem. It suggests that understanding is an effort.
I am not fully sure, how this works, though, neither in German nor in English, and I find it hard to describe the difference accurately.
German lassen
In the case of

I will see what can be done. ("Ich werd' mal schauen, was sich machen lässt.")

something else is going on. Here, German lassen gives rise to an idiomatic construction that does not exist in English. Similar to the construction make somebody do something, where the English expression cannot be translated literally  (German: jemanden dazu bringen etwas zu tun is possible, but by far not as idiomatic as make somebody do something in English), German etwas lässt sich tun has no idiomatic literal translation to English.
An example of how hard it can be to translate this German construction is the (ironic) expression

So lässt sich's aushalten.

It expresses that a situation is favorable, and could be translated in a literal way to "This is how it (life) can be endured."

The examples you gave can all be translated with "kann". It would not be uncommon usage.

I can make out the mountains in the distance. --> Ich kann die Berge in der Ferne erkennen.
as far as I can see --> So weit ich sehe
I'll see what can be done. --> Ich werde sehen, was getan werden kann.

Just as well, your English sentences can drop the can.

I can make out the mountains in the distance. --> I make out the mountains in the distance.
as far as I can see --> As far as I see
I'll see what can be done. --> I'll see what is doable.

In both languages, can/kann is used as a modal verb. It modifies another verb.
"I see" is stating that you see. "I can see" is stating that you are able to see. The first is doing the second is describing ability.
In German, it is the same.
Therefore, all your translations are not very literal. They are "likely translations" because they fit in many contexts. If you translate the German you provided to a more literal English, you would get this:

Ich erkenne die Berge in der Ferne. --> I make out/recognize the
mountains in the distance.
soweit ich sehe --> as far as I see
Ich will sehen, was sich tun lässt. --> I will see, what lets itself
be done.

As you can see the more literal translations have no "can".
Does this answer your question?

False friend alert: I will see... -> Ich werde sehen...

I agree that all examples can be translated using kann. I still agree with OP, that it is less idiomatic in German.

As a native English speaker I am sure no one would ever say "I make out the mountains in the distance" or "as far as I see." You have to use "can" in that context.

"Berge i.d. Ferne ausmachen (1)" wäre noch näher an einer wörtl. Übersetzung und nicht unüblich. "Werde sehen, was man tun kann" wäre m.E. idiomatischer als "getan werden kann(3)".

@planetmaker why? I will see has its literal meaning and the "I will check what can be done" meaning. Both can be used and depend on context.

@odduse_of_language example: You are on a ship and one of the sailors has good eyesight. He claims: "I will be the first to make out the mountains in the distance." Valid usage in that context. And no can is used. With "as far as I see" I share your opinion of it beeing very uncommon and I don't find an example that doesn't sound weird however can you prove that it is plain wrong? For example: "As far as I see into the future, it stays bad. You're truly unlucky."

@userunknown good points
